# I want to load website pages with slide effect

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, webforms, umbraco

I want to load website pages with slide effect similar [abnieh](http://danialz8.wix.com/abnieh1#!home2/cm7h).
It means when you are click the menu elements, the page changes with slide effect.
I use Umbraco CMS, ASP.NET Web Form and C#.NET.
How can I do it?

Please help me.

a part of my main master page is:

```
<form id="AbniyehMainForm" runat="server">
        <div id="MasterMaster" style="width: 100%;">
            <div>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ContentPlaceHolderDefault">
                    <div>
                        <uc1:HeaderControl runat="server" ID="HeaderControl" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="homePageContent"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="aboutUsContent">
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="serviceSectionContent">
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="projectSectionContent">
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="newsSectionContent">
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="contactUsSectionContent">
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </div>
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <div>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="languagesContent">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="menuContent">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a client side javascript effect, Most likely with jQuery and load the pages using ajax then slide the page in after it is loaded. I found this [Project](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide/) that looks like it will do what you want and here is a sample from a [tutorial](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/02/23/how-to-use-jquery-to-make-slick-page-transitions/).

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").css("display", "none");

    $("body").fadeIn(2000);

    $("a.transition").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);      
    });

    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
});
</script>
```

---

And here is how you load a page via ajax from the [jQuery website](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>load demo</title>
      <style>
      body {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: Arial;
      }
      </style>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

<b>Footer navigation:</b>
<ol id="new-nav"></ol>

<script>
$( "#new-nav" ).load( "/ #jq-footerNavigation li" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```